# Progress Bar and Color

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

My progress bar doesn't change the color! why? Only change on WPF
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove

```
Application.EnableVisualStyles();
```

from your `Program.cs`. See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.enablevisualstyles.aspx) for more information on EnableVisualStyles.

Answer (score 1):

You can't customize the green that is default for Windows 7/Vista.